# Why does AWS SES close the connection when attempting AUTH LOGIN?

Tags: smtp, aws-ses

I am attempting to send a test email via AWS SES. I have my smtp endpoint and smtp credentials all set up.

I am testing using the command `openssl s_client -crlf -connect email-smtp.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com:465`

```
220 email-smtp.amazonaws.com ESMTP SimpleEmailService-d-9DUAYPN33 LZr4P6RYoF17pFim8gwK
EHLO rassa
250-email-smtp.amazonaws.com
250-8BITMIME
250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN
250 Ok
AUTH LOGIN
334 VXNlcm5hbWU6
dXNlcm5hbWU=
DONE
```

The connection closes immediately after sending my base64 encoded username. Why is this, and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Using the s_client command: `openssl s_client -crlf -quiet -starttls smtp -connect email-smtp.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com:587` allowed me to get futher along in the authentication flow.

Received

```
235 Authentication successful.
```

After providing base64 username and password